# A recursive method to traverse a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, arrays, traversal

I need a method to traverse a multidimensional array in PHP without using function calls itself.

Basically I have an array like this:

```
$data = array(
    'hoge' => 123,
    'foo' => 456,
    'bar' => 789,
    'aaa' => array(
        'abc' => 111,
        'bcd' => 222,
        'cde' => 333
    ),
    'bbb' => array(
        'def' => array(
            'efg' => 'hoge'
        )
    ),
    'stacks' => array(
       'a',
       'b'=> array('qwe' => 111, 
                   'asd' => 222, 
                   'args' => array('1', 
                                   '2', 
                                   '3')),
       'c'
    )
);
```

Generally you use a function like this:

```
    function get_array_elems($arrResult, $where="array"){
      while(list($key,$value)=each($arrResult)){
        if (is_array($value)){
          get_array_elems($value, $where."[$key]");
        }
      } else {
        ...anything
      }
    }


get_array_elems($arrResult);
```

I can not use this method because i have to write this method in a PHP function and it can not write a function in another function.

Can it be done using an iterative method such as while, foreach, array_walk_recursive etc.?

Comment: May I ask why you cannot use a function call inside a function? And if you want to have an iterative approach, I would not put *recursive* into the question's title.

Answer (score 2):

`array_walk_recursive` will still work. Just use an anonymous function: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php as the callback. You can use anonymous functions inside other functions so it should work for you. Just make sure you are using at least **PHP 5.3.0** since thats when anonymous functions were introduced.

Comment: Just watch out... anonymous functions weren't introduced until PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Although I also cannot see how using a recursive function would be impossible, but as a programming excercise it is an interesting one.

If you were to mimic recursion, you should keep your own stack to keep track of your position in every level, but that's a real PITA, so if it's all the same you'd better first go through level 0, 1, 2 etc in that order and collect nested arrays as you go. E.g.:

```
function walk($walk)
{
    while ( count($walk) > 0 )
    {
        $defer = array();
        foreach ( $walk as $k=>$v )
        {   
            if ( is_array($v) )
            {       
                foreach ( $v as $kk=>$vv ) $defer["$k.$kk"] = $vv;
            } else {
                print "$k=>$v\n";
            }       
        }   
        $walk = $defer;
    }
}
```

but this obviously has different characteristics than the typical recursion solution, which may or may not be a problem.